# Where to find information about aircraft type knowing the flight number and date?

Tags: airline-operations, airlines

Having flight date and exact flight number, I would like to know aircraft type (like Boeing 737-400). Is there any service where I can get such information in bulk (for hundreds of flight dates and flight numbers)? I know that flightradar24 provides us with [similar data](http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/un190/), but it doesn't have any [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API) to get such information for many cases.

Comment: You are looking for the aircraft model, not the aircraft name.

Comment: @Federico also known as the aircraft type :)

Comment: @Federico, what is aircraft name then? ;)

Comment: to make a not-so-well-know example [this B-29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enola_Gay) was named "Enola Gay"

Comment: Side note: I believe KLM _name_ (all?) their planes. [List](http://www.zoekenvindalles.nl/topics/KLM-Vliegtuigen-Vloot/1447). Example: ["City of Lima"](http://www.ad.nl/ad/nl/5597/Economie/article/detail/2042805/2009/10/09/Passagiers-ontvluchten-spooktoestel-van-KLM.dhtml) @Federico

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat afaik, all commercial companies name their planes

Comment: @Federico, I'm fairly sure plenty of US carriers do not. It does seem pretty common in Europe, though. Icelandair does, as well, for example.

Answer (score 6):

[FlightAware](http://flightaware.com/) will give you all the info and [has an API](http://flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/).